# Cordova Crosswalk plugin - usage with Meteor 1.4.2.2 not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor, crosswalk

after a long unsuccessful search, I decided to post my question here. I'm trying to use the Cordova Crosswalk plugin with my Meteor app. I used the package from atmosphere

`meteor add crosswalk`

as well as the Cordova package from Github

`meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@2.2.0`

When I install the package in my app, everything works just fine, except if I build my app (the Android apk file) it does not contain crosswalk (apk size is at about 10 MB with or without the plugin).

The only hint I'm getting, when I build the app is the following

```
Crosswalk info:dova app for Android          |
    After much discussion and analysis of the market,
    we have decided to discontinue support for Android 4.0 (ICS) in Crosswalk starting with version 20,
    so the minSdkVersion of Cordova project is configured to 16 by default.
```

But this sounds more like an Info. I also added the following line to my mobile-config.js file, with no success

`app.setPreference('android-minSdkVersion', '16');`

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am running crosswalk@1.7.0 as a meteor package, but not the plugin (not necessary?) Try removing it

Comment: Hi @Mikkel, thanks for your response. As I described, I tried to use the meteor package but without success, the built apk is still only 10 MB in size, that means crosswalk was not added. Can ouy describe your build process? Is the apk including crosswalk being built in some other folder?

Comment: @mikkel one more question, can you please post your mobile-config.js Configuration? This would be very helpful for me! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is my mobile config. There is very little in the way of secret sauce here

```
// mobile-config.js
// This section sets up some basic app metadata,
// the entire section is optional.
App.info({
  id: 'com.senecto.amba.mcduck',
  version: '1.1.10',
  name: 'Amba.McDuck',
  description: 'Amba tablet - mcduck version',
  author: 'Mike King',
  email: 'contact@senecto.com',
  website: 'http://senecto.com'
});
// Set up resources such as icons and launch screens.
App.icons({
// 'iphone_2x        // (120x120)
// 'iphone_3x        // (180x180)
// 'ipad               // (76x76)
// 'ipad_2x          // (152x152)
// 'ipad_pro           // (167x167)
// 'ios_settings       // (29x29)
// 'ios_settings_2x  // (58x58)
// 'ios_settings_3x  // (87x87)
// 'ios_spotlight    // (40x40)
// 'ios_spotlight_2x   // (80x80)
'android_mdpi'    : 'public/res/icon/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png',     // (48x48)
'android_hdpi'    : 'public/res/icon/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png',   // (72x72)
'android_xhdpi'   : 'public/res/icon/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png',  // (96x96)
'android_xxhdpi'  : 'public/res/icon/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png',   // (144x144)
'android_xxxhdpi' : 'public/res/icon/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png'   // (192x192)//   
});
App.launchScreens({
// 'iphone_2x': 'public/res/screen.png',
// 'iphone5': 'public/res/screen.png',
// 'iphone6': 'public/res/screen.png',
// 'iphone6p_portrait': 'public/res/screen.png',
// 'iphone6p_landscape': 'public/res/screen.png',
// 'ipad_portrait': 'public/res/screen.png',
// 'ipad_portrait_2x': 'public/res/screen.png',
// 'ipad_landscape': 'public/res/screen.png',
// 'ipad_landscape_2x': 'public/res/screen.png',
'android_mdpi_portrait': 'public/res/screen.png',
'android_mdpi_landscape': 'public/res/screen.png',
'android_hdpi_portrait': 'public/res/screen.png',
'android_hdpi_landscape': 'public/res/screen.png',
'android_xhdpi_portrait': 'public/res/screen.png',
'android_xhdpi_landscape': 'public/res/screen.png',
'android_xxhdpi_portrait': 'public/res/screen.png',
'android_xxhdpi_landscape': 'public/res/screen.png'
  // 'iphone': 'splash/Default~iphone.png',
  // 'iphone_2x': 'splash/Default@2x~iphone.png',
  // ... more screen sizes and platforms ...
});
// Set PhoneGap/Cordova preferences
//App.setPreference('BackgroundColor', '0xff0000ff');
App.setPreference('HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar', true);
// App.setPreference('Orientation', 'landscape');
// App.setPreference('Orientation', 'landscape', 'android');
// App.setPreference('Orientation', 'landscape', 'ios');
App.setPreference('Fullscreen', 'true', 'android');
App.setPreference('Fullscreen', 'true', 'ios');
App.setPreference('android-targetSdkVersion', '23');
App.setPreference('WebAppStartupTimeout', 60000);
App.setPreference('AndroidPersistentFileLocation','Compatibility')

// Pass preferences for a particular PhoneGap/Cordova plugin
// App.configurePlugin('com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect', {
//   APP_ID: '1234567890',
//   API_KEY: 'supersecretapikey'
// });
// Add custom tags for a particular PhoneGap/Cordova plugin
// to the end of generated config.xml.
// Universal Links is shown as an example here.
// App.appendToConfig(`
//   <universal-links>
//     <host name="localhost:3000" />
//   </universal-links>
// `);

App.accessRule('blob:*');
App.accessRule('file:*');
App.accessRule('*');
App.accessRule('skype:*',{launchExternal: true});
```